# necesito saber como comparar dos registros en php con mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

El código es el siguiente, es para un proyecto de la universidad, estoy haciendo un modelo de copa y estoy por insertar partidos y necesito validar que las dos selecciones sean del mismo grupo, acá el código pero **no funciona**

```
<?php 
require_once 'conexion.php';
$seleccion1 = $_GET['Seleccion1'];
$seleccion2 = $_GET['Seleccion2'];

$grupo_seleccion1 = $con -> query("select Grupo from Seleccion where Nombre='$seleccion1'");
$grupo_seleccion2 = $con -> query("select Grupo from Seleccion where Nombre='$seleccion2'");
if($fila1 = $grupo_seleccion1 -> fetch_assoc()){
    $var1 = $fila1['Nombre'];
}


if($fila2 = $grupo_seleccion2 -> fetch_assoc()){
    $var2 = $fila2['Nombre'];
}
var_dump($var1);
if ( $var1 == $var2) {
    echo "Son del mismo grupo";
}
else{
    echo "No son del mismo grupo";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hay varios errores. Por ejemplo, tú estás seleccionado la columna `Grupo` en el `SELECT` y luego aquí buscas la columna `Nombre`, la cual nunca encontrarás porque no estás seleccionando esa columna: `$fila1['Nombre']`. Deberías cambiar por `$fila1['Grupo']` y `$fila2['Grupo']`  ... Los dos `if` no creo que sean necesarios y hasta creo que puedes resolver esto con una sola consulta si organizas bien el modelo de datos y usas tablas relacionadas con identificadores.

Answer (score 2):

Buenos amigos gracias ya encontré el problema estaba en que estaba llamando al campo erróneo solo cambie  `$fila1['Nombre']` y `$fila2['Nombre']` por
`$fila1['Grupo']` `$fila2['Grupo']` respectivamente gracias y  disculpen las molestias